# How to avoid MGT component to appears behind another

Tags: spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I'm using the Microsoft Graph Toolkit to display user information from a SharePoint SPFX webpart.

Specifically, I use the `mgt-person` and `mgt-person-card` components.

Unfortunately, there are some native components in the page that defines a `z-index:2` css rule (page title).

This leads to weird rendering :

[image: weird result]

Red is the `mgt-person` component, green is the `mgt-person-card` component and blue is the native page title.

As you can see, the mgt flyout is behind the page title. This is due to the z-index rules applied to the page title.

How to fix that ?

Reproduction (not SPFX) : https://jsfiddle.net/stevebeauge/5Lg7c63n/

I try to override the `z-index` rule in my webpart CSS, but this doesn't work.

I even wasn't able to find a DOM element where to apply a higher z-index (maybe due to the mess of web component and its shadow DOM).

The SPFX project was generated using the `@microsof/sharepoint` yeoman generator. I referenced the latest MGT npm package and in my webpart:

```
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      'mgt-person': any;
      'mgt-person-card': any;
      'template': any;
    }
  }
}
export default class MyWebpartProp extends React.Component<IMyWebpartProp, {}> {
  public render() {
    return (
              <div className={styles.resultContainer}>
                <mgt-person user-id="me" show-name show-email person-card="click">

                  <template data-type="person-card">
                    <mgt-person-card person-details="{{person}}" person-image="{{personImage}}">
                      <template data-type="additional-details">
                       ... some markup ...
                      </template>
                    </mgt-person-card>
                  </template>

                </mgt-person>
              </div>
            );

  }


}
```

Package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/decorators": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/mgt": "^1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-application-base": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-dialog": "1.10.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.15.1",
    "custom-event-polyfill": "^1.0.7",
    "jshint": "^2.11.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-2.9": "0.10.3",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "@types/chai": "4.2.8",
    "@types/mocha": "7.0.1",
    "ajv": "~6.11.0"
}
```

Comment: This is very timely as I just noticed this myself and I believe the issue is due to mgt rendering the flyouts with "position:absolute". We should really be using "position: fixed" . That requires us to handle additional edge cases though. Could you create an issue for this in the mgt repo: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Needs%3A+Triage+%3Amag%3A%2C+bug&template=bug_report.md&title=%5BBUG%5D

Comment: Just created the issue here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to provide closure here, this issue should be fixed as part of 1.2 update of the Microsoft Graph Toolkit.

Comment: Thanks for fix and feedback

Comment: with 1.3 there is some ts issues Error - [tsc] node_modules/lit-html/ts3.4/lib/parts.d.ts(108,32): error TS1005: ';' expected.